# does anyone know how to pass environment variables from appSetting.json to a docker windows container?

Tags: c#, .net, docker

When I run the command below in linux container it works, however when I do it on windows the container receives the environment variables but they do not replace the value in appSeting.Json and the connection is not made.

```
docker run -d -p 0.0.0.0:80:80 --name container-name --restart=always \
-e ConnectionStrings:DB_SERVIDOR="Data Source=12.124.241.12:1521/ORCLCDB;User ID=user;Password=123*"
```

Answer (score 0):

`:` has varying support across platforms - if you replace `:` with a double underscore `__` instead, it should work and is cross-platform. (Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-5.0#environment-variables)